# How to write POS tagged sentences to a text file using Python

Tags: python, nltk

I have used nltk to tokenize and POS tag a text, and want to write words & their tags to this text. I am not sure how to do the latter part. I am using Python 3.4. The following are my lines:

```
from nltk import pos_tag, word_tokenize
file = open('D:\English.txt')
raw = file.read()
token = word_tokenize(raw)
word_tag = pos_tag(token)
for x, y in word_tag:
    print((x), (y))
file.close()
```

The result looks like this:

```
Hello NNP
world NN
```

I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to write the result to this text (or a csv file).

---

Problem solved:

```
from nltk import pos_tag, word_tokenize
fr = open('D:\English_source.txt','r')
fw = open('D:\English_POS.txt','w')
raw = fr.read()
token = word_tokenize(raw)
word_tag = pos_tag(token)
for x, y in word_tag:
    fw.write(x+" "+y+"\n")
fw.close()
fr.close()
```

Thanks guys. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Such basics are easily found in [the official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). If you already tried that but it somehow failed, add that code to your question

Comment: @usr2564301 In the first example, the file is opened for reading, in the second, for writing. So, no, they are not the same.

Comment: Well that was hard to spot. Still, the error message ought to tell you something (if only that *this* is not enough to write to files). Have you checked out that link to the official tutorial?

Comment: Do you want to write the results into the same file? (And overwrite the original contents?) Then you should close the file after reading from it, ope it again for writing, and `file.write()` into it instead of printing.